# How can I pass connection parameter db to main.go?

Tags: go, beego

I have trouble with my current works. I build an apps using beego framework, Im new in golang.

First, I build other package called utils, and from that package I write some codes to access to my databases

```
func InitFirebird() {
    var (
        dbDriver   = beego.AppConfig.String("DB_CONNECTION")
        dbUsername = beego.AppConfig.String("DB_USERNAME")
        dbPassword = beego.AppConfig.String("DB_PASSWORD")
        dbServer   = beego.AppConfig.String("DB_HOST")
        // dbPort     = beego.AppConfig.String("DB_PORT")
        dbFileName = beego.AppConfig.String("DB_DATABASE")
    )
    conn, _ := sql.Open(dbDriver, dbUsername+":"+dbPassword+"@"+dbServer+"/"+dbFileName)
    defer conn.Close()
}
```

After that, I go to my main.go and setting up my init function and main function like this:

```
func init() {
    utils.InitFirebird()
}

func main() {
    if beego.BConfig.RunMode == "dev" {
        beego.BConfig.WebConfig.DirectoryIndex = true
        beego.BConfig.WebConfig.StaticDir["/swagger"] = "swagger"
        }

    var n int

    conn.QueryRow("SELECT Count(*) FROM rdb$relations").Scan(&n)
    fmt.Println("Relations count=", n)

    beego.Run()
}
```

When I startover my apps, its error and provide me this message :

`\main.go:23:2: undefined: conn`

How can I resolve this?

Anyhelp will appreciate

Comment: utils is a separate package? and main function is in a separate package?

Comment: yes i create a folder called utils, and I create a file named firebird.go inside utils to store my database preferences. I want call those globally in main.go and to others package @Praveen

Comment: Don't ignore errors. If you have a connection error `conn` will be nil, and you won't know, because you're ignoring errors.

Comment: ah I see, I will add the handling later, I just curious with this case @Flimzy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you want to access something from another package, it has to be exported. In Go, if you want to export something you name it with first letter as uppercase (in your case, it should be `Conn` instead of `conn`).

Second, when you use `defer` it will get executed when the function returns. In your case, it returns immediately, so the connection is closed immediately.

**Solution:**

```
var Conn *sql.DB
func InitFirebird() {
    var (
        dbDriver   = beego.AppConfig.String("DB_CONNECTION")
        dbUsername = beego.AppConfig.String("DB_USERNAME")
        dbPassword = beego.AppConfig.String("DB_PASSWORD")
        dbServer   = beego.AppConfig.String("DB_HOST")
        // dbPort     = beego.AppConfig.String("DB_PORT")
        dbFileName = beego.AppConfig.String("DB_DATABASE")
    )
    Conn, _ = sql.Open(dbDriver, dbUsername+":"+dbPassword+"@"+dbServer+"/"+dbFileName)
}
```

Now in your main package:

```
func init() {
    utils.InitFirebird()
}

func main() {
    if beego.BConfig.RunMode == "dev" {
        beego.BConfig.WebConfig.DirectoryIndex = true
        beego.BConfig.WebConfig.StaticDir["/swagger"] = "swagger"
        }

    var n int
    defer utils.Conn.Close() // <-- Close here

    utils.Conn.QueryRow("SELECT Count(*) FROM rdb$relations").Scan(&n)
    fmt.Println("Relations count=", n)

    beego.Run()
}
```

Here `Close()` won't get executed immediately because `beego.Run()` will block.

**PS:**
Passing DB connection using global variable is not recommended. If you want to learn more check this out: https://www.alexedwards.net/blog/organising-database-access

Comment: Thanks for the answer. once again, if I create a new package (new folder), can I still access the Conn variable in other packages?